# jquery-week-calendar: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'classes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui, jquery-week-calendar

I'm using jquery-week-calendar with this jQuery bundle:

- jquery: 3.1.1
- jquery-mousewheel: 3.1.13
- jquery-typeahead: 2.7.6
- jquery-mask-plugin: 1.14.9
- jquery-countTo: 1.2.0
- jquery-steps: 1.1.0
- chart.js: 2.5.0
- dropify: "0.2.1
- jquery-ui: 1.12.1
- jquery-week-calendar-ui: latest

I get this error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'classes' of undefined
```

And this is the Stacktrace:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'classes' of undefined
at String.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:12672:11129)
at Function.each (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:374:19)
at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._resolveClassesValues (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:12672:11094)
at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._resolveClassesValues (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:12670:4499)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:12672:9373)
at Function.each (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:368:19)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:157:17)
at String.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:12672:9205)
at Function.each (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:374:19)
at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._initWidgets (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:12672:8750)
```

The error is fired by a minified jQuery-UI code.
Any suggest on how to fix this?

Comment: What should we answer you? You even didn't provide us code that causes the issue. Open devtools and follow by stack trace

Comment: Sorry, now I add my stacktrace..

Comment: The error starts from `_initWidgets` method. Put breakpoint there and look at callstack

Comment: @yurzui ok, i've followed the stacktrace with the debugger, and jQuery-ui try to do that `var o=i.options.classes[n] || " "` where `i` is an array of NodeElement (a button i think) but there is no `options` attribute in `i`

Comment: It means that you didn't provide options somewhere

Comment: Probably yes, but i've simply copied and pasted the example..

Comment: I got this error message with with a call to jQuery IU's buttonset() after I upgraded jQuery to 3.4. I think searching for buttonset() calls (which should be upgraded to ControlGroup) would be a good first step. After that,  try to isolate which jQuery IU widget call might be the culprit